# Вывод информации с помощью ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Подскажите примерчиком как на сторону клиента вывести содержимое таблицы из postgre с использованием ExtJS 3.4.
формат вывода таблица с прокруткой к примеру.
спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поискать [тут](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel). Это простой пример.

Документация хоть и на английском, но очень подробная и понятная.